# parsing infinite list into one list

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have this task building a code using recursion. The task is taking a list who can have an infinite amount of lists inside it and making it one list.

This is so far what I have:

```
def flat_list(array):
    new_array =[]
    for i in range(0,len(array)):
        if len(str(array[i])) > 1:
            flat_list(array[i:i+1])
        else:
            new_array += array[i:len(str(array))-1]
            return new_array
```

These are the tests it needs to pass:

```
assert flat_list([1, 2, 3]) == [1, 2, 3]
assert flat_list([1, [2, 2, 2], 4]) == [1, 2, 2, 2, 4]
assert flat_list([[[2]], [4, [5, 6, [6], 6, 6, 6], 7]]) == [2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
assert flat_list([-1, [1, [-2], 1], -1]) == [-1, 1, -2, 1, -1]
```

Mine returns this:

```
flat_list([1, [2, 2, 2], 4])
my result: [1,[2,2,2],4]
right answer: [1,2,2,2,4]
```

I think my problem is with creating a new local variable of the new_array at each entry, How can I return one list with no other lists inside it?

This task is without using numpy, but if you can also show me how it can be done with numpy it will really educate me. :)
Thank you for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def flatten(S):
if S == []:
    return S
if isinstance(S[0], list):
    return flatten(S[0]) + flatten(S[1:])
return S[:1] + flatten(S[1:])
```

How it works:
1. The list is passed as an argument to a recursive function to flatten the list.
2. In the function, if the list is empty, the list is returned.
3. Otherwise the function is recursively called with the sublists as the parameters until the entire list is flattened.

Comment: If it did, can you select the answer as a "accepted" using the green check under the score panel, which is next to the answer post?

Comment: Now i get it, thanks alot, is using numpy even shorter?

Comment: Often you will see that the "best" code is not the code that is short, but the one that is readable.

Comment: I will select it, just waiting for the option to open in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following suggestion: it iterates over the list and if the encountered item is a list, then it recursively flattens it before appending it to the resulting flattened list:

```
def flat_list(aList):
    result = []
    for i in aList:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            result += flat_list(i)
        else:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```